# I am getting hundred's of this:- E/AudioCache(32): Heap size overflow! req size: 1050624, max size: 1048576

Tags: android

I am creating a word builer game.In this i have used around 80 images and have used many objects globaly.Is that a reason that i m getting this type of message in logcat?

Comment: The heap is where objects are stored once created and if your heap is overflowing it is because of too many objects present.